# React Native logout functionality not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication, logout

Hy, I'm creating the react-native app in native-cli. I'm trying first-time navigation 5. when I do the login I receive the Token and store it in AsyncStorage but need to reload the app to move toward the dashboard so to solve this I used the useContext and its working fine but now the issue is that when I login the app and move around it and then press the logout button it works nicely but when I login the app surf the app and then press the back button go to the home screen of mobile without logout then again when I come back to the app and press log out it clear the AsyncStorge but not log out the app and I need to refresh then it goes back to the login screen.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
  const [log, setLog] = useState(0)
  const [role, setRole] = useState('seller')
    //console.log('App.js-Start')
  console.log("app_User:",user);
  console.log("app_log:",log);
  useEffect(()=>{ 
    getKeysData(dataKeys)
  },[]) 
  const dataKeys = ['token', 'super_user_status', 'isLoggedIn'];    
  const getKeysData = async (keys) => {
    const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
    //console.log(stores)
    // const aData = stores.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
    const aData = await Promise.all(stores.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})))
    const token = aData[0]['token']
    const super_user_status = aData[1]['super_user_status']
    const isLoggedIn = aData[2]['isLoggedIn']
    console.log('token',token)
    console.log('SuperUser', super_user_status)
    console.log('Log',isLoggedIn)
    //setUser(isLoggedIn)
      if(isLoggedIn == 1){
        setLog(1)
      }
    
    }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <LoginContext.Provider value={{user,setUser}} >
      { user == false && log==0  ?
        <AuthStackScreen />
        :
        <BuyerDashboardStackScreens /> 
      }
      </LoginContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Login**

```
 await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: api + 'login/',
                data: login_Credentials,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            }).then(async function (response) {
                if (response.data.success == true) {
                    const token = response.data.token.toString();
                    const super_user_status = response.data.super_user_status.toString();
                    const isLoggedIn = "1"
                    //console.log('Logged In and set Storgae')
                    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['isLoggedIn',isLoggedIn],['token', token], ['super_user_status', super_user_status]])
                    setUser(true)
                    setEmail('')
                    setPassword('')
                    setPress(false)
                }
```

**logout**

```
  const logOut = () => {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    setUser(false);
  };
```

Comment: You need to detect "coming back to the app", check the login status and proceed accordingly.

Comment: You could clear the storage and then navigate back to your login screen

Comment: @yesIamFaded there two stack one is authStack and other is buyerDashboardStack. so I can't navigate it

Comment: @ChrisG I try but I didn't find something

Comment: Use this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: On logout setLog(0) so that both conditions that are in navigation container met.